How to import an array of rows while editing each row of the array
I have a complicated question
I have one table with a bunch of columns and rows. Then on other pages I import filtered data from the first page. That is, I group all the data into separate groups via =query(General!B3:L9999999; "where G contains 'value' order by J desc"; 0). But because of this all the formatting of the main page is lost, namely the links from the cells are erased. It is not very difficult to return the links to the cells, it is enough to insert a similar formula =IF(ISBLANK(A3);;HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("https://my.url="; SUBSTITUTE(A3; " "; "_")); SUBSTITUTE(A3; " "; "_")))
But the problem is that the table is not static, every day it will have more and more new rows on the main page, which will be imported to the filtered pages. Therefore, I need to insert such a formula in each row from A3 to A9999999. And I find it inconvenient
In connection with this I finally come to the question. Is it possible to combine two formulas into one? I mean my above written
=IF(ISBLANK(A3);;HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("https://my.url="; SUBSTITUTE(A3; " "; "_")); SUBSTITUTE(A3; " "; "_")))

and
=ArrayFormula('Filter'!A3:A9999999)

Or is there some other way to do what I need to do?

Related question: How to keep the hyperlink while using =QUERY formula in google spreadsheet?, How to Query data while adding a hyperlink at the end of each entry that links to the source?.

Would you please share a sample sheet with realistic-demo data and expected output (manually entered) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker provided by docs community forum in case you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

link I think this will only confuse you


You may try with filter() for the hyperlinks to stay as-is:
=filter(Main!B:M,Main!G:G="General")



It looks like it's a working option. It's just strange that I can't vote for the answer to my own question. The rest of you have to decide which answer suits me?

K14M, as the person who asked the question, you aren’t allowed to vote. BUT… you can “accept” the best/ most helpful answer.
